# Apply VLookup on all sheets of excel file in one shot along with description

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a Data in ExcelFile 1 which look something like this
COl A
1
2
3
4
5
6

I have another excel file  'ExcelFile2' which contains over 50 sheets .
The data in this file contains  two column - COlA is similar to ColA of ExcelFile1 and Col2 is Description .

My requirement  is to Check what data in ExcelFile1 is matching from any sheet in ExcelFile2 and find what is the description  from Col2 in ExcelFile2

Applying  VLookup on each sheet will take forever . Is there a simpler  automated way of achieving  this ?

Looking for the help on this as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

To Vlookup multiple sheets at a time, carry out these steps:

Write down all the lookup sheet names somewhere in your workbook and name that range (Lookup_sheets in our case).

Adjust the generic formula for your data. In this example, we'll be:
searching for A2 value (lookup_value)
in the range A2:A6 (lookup_range) in four worksheets (s1, s2, s3, s4), and
pull matching values from column B, which is column 2 (col_index_num) in the data range A2:C6 (table_array).
With the above arguments, the formula takes this shape:

=VLOOKUP($A2, INDIRECT("'"&INDEX(Lookup_sheets, MATCH(1, --(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"& Lookup_sheets&"'!$A$2:$A$6"), $A2)>0), 0)) &"'!$A$2:$C$6"), 2, FALSE)

This is an array forumula so Ctrl+Shift+Enter

[image: print sreen]

Comment: Can you elaborate how did C6 come in to picture ?
Also , if i need to search only from COL A in all worksheets , what can we the formula?

Comment: i just extended the lookup table from A2 to C6, if you just wnat two columns put B6.
so sheet s1 lookup table A2:C6 and so on.